# SharePoint 2010 show subsites dropdown menu link broken

Tags: 2010, sub-site, top-link-bar

[image]

I have a main site (Planning) that has the "Show subsites" option enabled in the navigation settings. All the links work correctly except for one of the subsites comes up with a "website cannot be found", "http 404". However, if I click on the parent site and select all site content, the link under sites and workspaces works just fine. I do notice the link on the drop down menu has /sitepages/home.aspx after the subsite name, versus the link under sites and workspaces ends with just the subsite name. Is there a way I can manually edit the dropdown menu link to match the sites and workspaces link? I've been through all the settings and still can't find anything that will allow this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it added from "Navigation" settings under "Site Settings"?

Comment: Yes, all those subsites are automatically added to a dropdown menu when I check the show subsites box on the Planning (parent) site. But there is no way to edit the individual link for each page. All the other subsite links work.